# How to create a vector starting with zero in R?

Tags: r, signal-processing

I need to create a vector of values starts from 0 and ends at 0.5000

Here's the data

```
rate=10000;

dur=0.5;

d<- 0:1/dur:rate
```

`d<- 0:1/dur:rate` this code keeps starting from 0.5

I tried `rep(0:1/dur:rate)`, `c(0:1/dur:srate)` and `seq(dur:rate, by=0:1)`

None of those worked

Does anyone know other options?

The answer should start with 0, 0.0001,0.0002......0.5000

Comment: Don’t mix `<-` and `=`. Pick one and stick with it. Consistently formatted code lowers the cognitive load and is easier to read.

Comment: Use `seq()`.  Read the help page to find the right arguments to use.  I'd recommend `from`, `to` and `by`.  You could use `length.out` instead of `by`.

Comment: Your problem is due to operator precedence. Use brackets.

Comment: @Limey where to put the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code that works as you expected:

```
rate <- 0.0001;
dur <- 0.5;
d <- seq(from=0, to=dur, by=rate)
print(d)
```